# Changing User-Name on https://myapps.developer.ubuntu.com/dev/

Tags: single-sign-on

I am facing some problems, I want to change login name on

https://myapps.developer.ubuntu.com/dev/

Can any one tell me how to do that? Screenshot is attached for reference
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described at https://answers.launchpad.net/launchpad/+faq/53 you can change your username by visiting https://launchpad.net/people/+me/+edit -- if the desired name is free.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can change your sign-in name, as the login is based on the Ubuntu / Launchpad OpenID service, and the sign-in name is part of the URI that uniquely identifies your user.

Answer (score 1):

To change your login details you can go at https://login.ubuntu.com and from there you can edit your name, manage your emails or change your password.